# "In" or "under" the shade of a tree

Tags: prepositions

1. > He sat **under** the shade of a tree.
2. > He sat **in** the shade of a tree.

Why is the first sentence wrong?

This was a question on an exam where I was given a sentence to fill up with appropriate preposition. The question was:

> He sat **UNDER/IN/INTO/ON** the shade of a tree.

The answer to this is IN the shade of a tree but I am not sure why? Because I marked UNDER the shade of a tree.

Comment: Oald, shade, no. 1  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shade_1?q=shade

Comment: @rogermue - Aha! See? I _knew_ someone was being a little over-the-top by saying that "in the shade" is "incorrect." SeemaB - Don't beiieve everything you read in these exam questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's because the object of the preposition is not 'tree' (in which case you would use 'under'), but 'shade', and 'the shade of the tree' is either the three-dimensional space you can be in and have the shadow of the tree fall on you, or the area on the ground where the shadow falls. In either case, it's something you sit in, rather than under.

Comment: I think you've solved the puzzle, but it's worth mentioning that many (if not most) English speakers wouldn't consider the first one "wrong" in everyday speech. The second might be more technically correct, but I find the first to be idiomatically acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

We often think of shadow as lying on the the ground.  As he sits within the area that is shaded, he is still clearly visible and simply appears to be sitting in the shade that surrounds him.

To be under something visible, it would have to be above him.  He is sitting under the tree whose branches extend above him.

Comment: RE: _to be under it, something would have to be above him..._ That's not always true, though. For example, we can be _under a spell, under the influence, under duress,_ etc. (I don't mean to nitpick, but I think it's important to state such caveats, lest learners read an answer like this one and come away under the impression that there's nothing more to it. Prepositions are extremely flexible, which is why I'm not sure I'd even agree that the first is even "wrong.")

Comment: @J.R. I agree. I edited my answer to limit it to the visible.

Answer (score 0):

Because you sit under the branch of the tree, but the shade isn't over you.  It’s around you and on the ground.  So you sit in the shadow of the shade.

Comment: Something about “the shadow of the shade” seems redundant.

Comment: @tchrist - I agree, but not necessarily in the case of trying to explain the O.P.'s question.